# can't get the styles and some scripts without log in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I deploy a web application in MVC3, the problem it's that can't the styles related with the layout because required authentication, so what can i do for This??. Do i need another configuration in my web.config?

**UPDATE**

So i modified my web.config but still without work, here's my web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

    <location path="Content">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="Scripts">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="js">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="Images">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="10" />

    </authentication>



    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**update II**

this is the method of my controller

```
 public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/LogOn

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            clsEncriptacion _clsEncriptacion = new clsEncriptacion();
            string encripPassword = _clsEncriptacion.Encriptar(model.Password);

            Usuario user = (from U in _db.Usuario
                            where ((U.Nombre == model.UserName) && (U.Password == encripPassword))
                            select U).FirstOrDefault();



            if (user != null)
            {
                Session["IdPerfil"] = user.Perfil_FK.Nivel.ToString();
                Session["IDUsuario"] = user.ID;
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user.Nombre, true);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                Session["IdPerfil"] = string.Empty;
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login o password incorrecto. Por favor, intente nuevamente.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Do i need another configuration in my IIS??

Comment: How do you do your authentication? The code that check only admin folder is restricted. How do you do it?

Comment: i create my own method in the controller

Comment: sure... let me update my question

Comment: ready, the question was updated

Comment: So after logging in as admin, you are able to view the assets? Are you sure the URL is correct? Is the website visible?

Comment: What happens if you add something like _routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}") as your first route in your Global.asax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the following in your web config:

```
<location path="admin/asset">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

assuming `admin/asset` is where you put your css and images

Comment: if i'm using the folder Content by default it should work putting only `"Content"` in the path???

Comment: Yes. On /web.config insert 
<location path="Content">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

Comment: I updated my question because I added this configuration but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow anonymous access to your resources, else they won't be served up.

In web.config, use something like:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="mystyles.css">
       <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/> 
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```